# Perl inconsistently prints strings that contain specific combinations of '%'

Tags: perl, printf

Can anyone please explain this perl behavior that i came across?

```perl
printf("%what_the\n");
printf("\%what_the\n");
```

Prints:

```
%what_the
%what_the
```

***WHILE***...

```perl
printf("%tomorrow\n");
printf("\%tomorrow\n");
```

Prints:

```
0morrow
0morrow
```

...***EVEN WITH `warnings` and `strict`***:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
printf("\%tomorrow\n");
```

Prints:

```
Missing argument in printf at - line 3.
0morrow
```

Comment: Do you have `use warnings; use strict;` at the beginning of your perl script like you should?

Comment: Warnings in particular will tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: And `use diagnostics;` will give you even more information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`printf` is different from regular `print`. You might be thinking it is the same, it is not. `printf` takes a pattern, which includes `%`. For example:

```
printf "%s\n", "tomorrow";   # prints "tomorrow\n"
```

`%s` is a placeholder for a string, which should be the second argument to `printf`.

The warning you get shows you the problem

```
Missing argument in printf at - line 3.
```

`printf` expects a second argument, because you have supplied a placeholder.

Not all letters following a percent sign is a valid combination, here's a few from the documentation from `sprintf`

```
%%    a percent sign
%c    a character with the given number
%s    a string
%d    a signed integer, in decimal
%u    an unsigned integer, in decimal
%o    an unsigned integer, in octal
%x    an unsigned integer, in hexadecimal
%e    a floating-point number, in scientific notation
%f    a floating-point number, in fixed decimal notation
%g    a floating-point number, in %e or %f notation
.... more
```

I do not see `%to` in there, but it seems to be what is being triggered. It prints a `0` because it casts the empty string (missing argument) to `0`.

Documentation [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf).

Comment: TL;DR: don't use printf to print a string, use print

Comment: (`%t` is for an argument of type `ptrdiff_t`. In Perl, that would be a signed integer.)

Answer (score 4):

The way to escape a % sign is to double it, *not* by a backslash.  `%o` is the format for printing an octal number.  Try doing `printf "%tomorrow", 255;`.  The `t` is a modifier flag on `%o` to set the integer type.

https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf#size

HTH